# How do I use access.properties variables in an Azure Spring Boot deployed app?

Tags: spring-boot, azure, production-environment

I have an Azure App Service, that's running my **Spring Boot App**, but in certain classes, I use the **@Value("${}")** annotation, to access variables from **access.properties** file. But it seems not to be working in the deployed app (production).

Comment: How is it deployed in production? Is it a JAR or a WAR, is it running in a Docker container? When you say `access.properties`, I suspect Spring-Boot is looking in the default `application.properties` file.

Comment: It´s a .jar, and I´m not running a container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Answering my question]**

As it looks like, I can simply put the application.properties variables in **Setting > Configuration > Application Settings** tab, adding as a **name:value** pairs

Then Spring already finds the values with the **@Value("${name}")** annotation

[image: twitter API configs]

BONUS: The application.properties file, should be like this, if you are using **Git CI/CD**

[image]